# How to hide Angular component inside AngularJS code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular

I have `MyTableComponent` Angular component rendered from AngularJS code:

```
// AngularJS code
// src/template/expanded-table.html
   ...
   <div class="table-view-port">
      <my-table ng-show="false" [model]="tableModel"
                                [dataSource]="data">
      </my-table>
   </div>
   ...
```

In Angular `MyTableComponent` I have:

```
// Angular code
// shared/components/table/table.component.ts

...
export class MyTableComponent<T> implements OnInit {
    ...
    ngOnInit() {
        console.log('Table component');
    }
    ...
```

All I need to do is **not** render `my-table` at all. I try to do it by using `ng-show="false"`, but it doesn't work. I tried `*ngIf="false"` either, but had the same result.

My downgrade module if it can affect somehow:

```
// appModule/app.module.downgrade.ts 

const APP_MODULE_DOWNGRADABLES: Mapper[] = [
    ...
    {
        downgradeAs: 'directive',
        entity: {
            component: MyTableComponent
        },
        targetName: 'myTable'
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ng-show is an angularJs directive which renders an html element, and then **hides** it if the condition is not meant, *ngIf is an **Angular** directive, if you don't want the element to render, you sould use `ng-if="false"`, which is the correct angularJs syntax.

see [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf)